# communication between an iframe and the page its part of through javascript in ie8

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have seen many questions like this but have not found anything that seems to help with my specific situation so I apologize if this question seems repetitive.

I have a site www.foo.com and have an iframe in it. When information I click on an a tag in foo.com a javascript function is called that passes a new image to the iframe to show the user. The communication between iframe and its "parent" seems to work fine on all browsers EXCEPT RANDOM IE8 PAGES. I get the following error message "access is denied" and the browser points to the function that has been activated. Following is a piece of code from the site to see how it works.

the iframe:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="foo.com/bar" id="ifram" name="ifram"></iframe>
```

the a tag:

The javascript:

```
if($(this).val() == '242'){
    document.getElementById('ifram').style.border='0px';
    document.getElementById('ifram').style.background = "url('../product_images/uploaded_images/Flag.jpg')";
    document.frames.ifram.document.body.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
```

This is just a snippet of a code and does not include the whole process of the ajax call to get the image but was not sure if the ajax is part of the issue. I get an undefined error in firefox but the function still fires . I am assuming I would just need to use window.frames for firefox.

Overall, any help on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated. I am wondering if there is a security issue that has to do with browser settings or if its part of how I coded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that if your iframe *tag* is on a page located at `http://www.foo.com` but the iframe points to `http://foo.com` it's considered a sandboxing violation and you'll get access denied.  Make sure you're pointing to the same domain as your page is on.  You can use relative URLs in the iFrame src tag, too, so you can change it to `src="bar.php"` (without any domain information).

Comment: I keep getting Webpage error details
 
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.2; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 12 Jan 2012 20:05:20 UTC
 
 
Message: Access is denied.
 
Line: 103
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI:....

Comment: Cool.  Did you try making sure the `src=` and the URL of the webpage are both on the same domain name, like my answer said?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use  `document.frames` before `document.frames.ifram.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";`. Just `ifram.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";` will do.